# Is 'Apart from by...' grammatically correct

Tags: grammaticality

While writing a news report, I found myself phrasing a sentence like this:

"Apart from by the managing director, the report would be reviewed by three specially constituted teams."

Though I immediately changed the sentence into active, I wondered if "Apart from by..." was grammatical.

I searched for the exact phrase in Google. It turned out about 222,000 results. But I could not find any 'reputable' source (at least not in the first few pages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly grammatical, but rather clumsy.

*Apart from* functions as a preposition. And, though prepositions normally  take noun phrases as their complement, they can sometimes take a prepositional phrase.

Other examples of this construction are

> There were papers all over the floor, *as well as on* the table.
>
> The queue stretched from the theatre *to beyond* the bank.

Note, incidentally, that *apart from by* is not structurally a component of the sentence: the structure is *[apart from [by the managing director]]*.

Comment: Thanks for your informed and lucid answer. The note and the examples were helpful.

Comment: Let me step out from behind my tree and tell you the story of a little boy who asked his father, "Daddy, what did you bring that book that I don't want to be read to out of about Down Under up for?"

Comment: Reg, go ahead, tell us the story.